# Getting a relative positioned element's absolute top and bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, upload

I have taken the risk of styling input type = file element with placing a button over it, after making it invisible, on a page where content keeps updating every now and then. When any content is added or deleted, the position of the button over the input changes, and it loses the position where it was exactly in front of the input type = file element. Can anyone give me anything in which i would be able to get the relative positions(top and bottom) of the element and translate it to absolute positions. I know it might sound silly, but dont vote it down, if there is a way, please help me, or you can give me a suggestion about it.

Comment: try wrapping the whole thing with a div with position relative and its child elements with position absolute and use z-index to position the elements above one another.

Comment: this is the answer ^, you should copy the text in Answer This Question and I would mark it as an answer to let this help in case this happens with someone else.

Comment: Was waiting for your feedback...added to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping the whole thing with a div with position relative and its child elements with position absolute and use z-index to position the elements above one another.